# Create a master detail page in apex with two details

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I just wanna know how to create a master detail with two editable details or master detail with a sub detail page in apex, i cant figure it out.

Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to 

refine your question with additional information, such as code and error message to describe your programming problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create one master Interactive grid.
Create another Interactive grid and there is an option under Master Detail called master region and choose the first grid you created.
Then choose the column that has the foreign key back to the first grid. There is a option on the column under master detail called Master column and choose the column in the first grid the foreign links to.

Comment: the problem is when i do that the app gives me this error "Interactive Grid 'NAME' doesn't have a master column defined which is required for a master detail relationship." and i dont know where to put the relationship. im using apex 5.1.1

Comment: Great, I found the solution, it was exactly like you said the only thing was to select the grid, assign a master page and then select the column that would be your FK and look for the option of master column and assign it. Thanks